# « As-tu déjà... » ou « As-tu jamais... » ?

Tags: sens, indications-de-temps, adverbes

À propos de ces 2 questions :

1. *As-tu déjà goûté le caviar ?*
2. *As-tu jamais goûté le caviar ?*

Sont-elles correctes ?
Si elles sont toutes les deux correctes, quelle est éventuellement leur différence sémantique ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si on veut les opposer, la différence entre *déjà* et *jamais* est que le premier suppose que ce dont il est question va finir se faire si ce ne l'est pas encore.

Mais *jamais* est fortement lié au fait qu'il est utilisé dans *ne ... jamais*, son utilisation dans un sens positif est devenue recherchée et on utilise souvent *déjà* quand on pourrait utiliser *jamais*, perdant une partie de la nuance.

À noter qu'il est un cas où la substitution ne se fait pas: quand le moment considéré se place dans le futur.  P.E. *Si jamais tu goûtes du caviar...*

Autre chose.  L'utilisation d'un article défini (*le*) plutôt que d'un article partitif (*du*) rends *jamais* improbable.  Le caviar dont il est question est bien déterminé et ce n'est pas n'importe lequel (vraisemblablement celui servit à la réception en cours) et ce contexte déterminé rend l'utilisation de *déjà* est plus naturel car il est naturel de penser que *tu* goûteras le caviar dans ce contexte (ou le goûterais si on ne t'en dissuadait pas en commentant sa qualité déplorable).

Answer (score 6):

Si je demande à quelqu'un :

> **As-tu déjà goûté le caviar ?**

Je veux savoir s'il a déjà goûté le caviar que j'ai acheté et rangé dans le placard. Je pourrais dire aussi *As-tu goûté le caviar* ?

> **As-tu jamais goûté du caviar ?**

Je veux savoir si la personne à laquelle je m'adresse a déjà eu dans sa vie l'occasion de manger du caviar. Il s'agit de faire parler la personne sur l'existence d'une expérience.
À noter que dans cette phrase je n'emploierais personnellement pas l'article défini car je ne parle pas ici d'un caviar spécifique.

Ceci dit il arrive qu'on emploie *déjà* à la place de *jamais* pour s'enquérir d'une expérience déjà vécue. Mais pour le faire il faut que le contexte ne permette aucune ambiguïté. Ce qui n'est pas le cas des deux phrases proposées dans la question, ou alors il aurait fallu mettre *du*, et pas *le*, dans les deux phrases.

Des exemples de phrases pour lesquelles je trouve que l'emploi de *déjà* ou de *jamais* ne change pas le sens de la question :

> As-tu jamais rêvé que tu volais ?
> As-tu déjà rêvé que tu volais ?
>
> As-tu jamais pensé que tu pouvais parfois te tromper ?
> As-tu déjà pensé que tu pouvais parfois te tromper ?

Donc la différence d'emploi entre *déjà* et *jamai*s dans une question est essentiellement contextuelle.

Comment: Ne serait-il pas plus approprié d'écrire la phrase de cette façon : "***N**'as-tu jamais goûté du caviar?*" ?

Comment: @Sifu Non. Je suis en ce point d'accord avec le  commentaire de Stéphane Gimenez à la réponse qui a été effacée sur cette page.

Answer (score 0):

La question avec "jamais" demande si la personne a accompli la chose à un moment de sa vie.

Dans un contexte général de temps, la question avec "déjà" a un sens identique. La version "jamais" est cependant plus littéraire; la version "déjà" est celle que l'on entendra dans le langage courant (hors régionalismes, le français variant beaucoup géographiquement).

Dans le contexte où le caviar est sur la table, "déjà" sous-entend que le caviar a été ou sera goûté, dans un passé ou un avenir proches. On demande ici si la personne a été rapide.

Answer (score 0):

Selon Wordreference, l'emploi de "jamais" pour exprimer "Have you ever...?" est un choix plus soutenu, tandis que "déjà" se dit plus fréquemment en conversation. Aurait-on l'air snob si l'on utilise le premier au lieu du dernier en conversation? Personnellement, je préfère "jamais" pour éviter de la confusion avec "already."  Est-ce que j'ai raison?

Comment: "Jamais" dans ce sens-là est effectivement soutenu, je ne l'utiliserais jamais dans une conversation normale.

Comment: J'ai l'impression que c'est une mauvaise idée de comparer à l'anglais et de vouloir éviter le sens de "already". En français courant, "déjà" signifie à la fois ever, yet et already. C'est au reste de la phrase d'être suffisamment explicite : "As-tu déjà fini ton gâteau ?" (yet), "Tu as déjà fini ton gâteau !" (already), "As-tu déjà goûté de ce gâteau ?" (ever).

Answer (score 0):

Selon moi, on dirait quelque chose comme "N'as-tu jamais mangé de caviar?" si cela était l'expression d'une surprise par rapport à une expérience non vécue plus que la formulation d'une question réelle.
Si ce qui m'intéresse est de savoir si la personne a fait ou non l'expérience, je dirais simplement: "As-tu déjà mangé du caviar?"